# My div ID is not styling - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

**Question 1: css doesn't style div id**

In my html file I've created a div id for a top bar (with text + social links). In the related css file I've created the corresponding style

```css
#topbar {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #383433;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#topbar p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <p>Text text text</p>
</div>
```

The text becomes white, but the height, background color etc. isn't coming through. Am I overlooking something?

**Question 2: can I style an image as part of a div id?**

Html:

```
<div id="scroller">
        <img src="images/scroller-1.jpg">
</div>
```

When I add:

```
 #scroller {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The image doesn't get responsive / resized.

If I add:

```
#scroller img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

It works.

So elements part of a div-id don't inherit the parent-style?

Comment: Question 1 is definitely working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/vw5v6027/.

Comment: Question 2: No they don't (not all anyway, text styles are generally inherited though).

Comment: First thing is doing it right : http://plnkr.co/edit/5Rx3lTGoUexTXFQy3YPh?p=preview
Maybe you may disable cache in your browser, some changes may not have been taken

Comment: For your first question, if you're background color is not displaying then you've likely removed it from the document flow so it `p` no longer takes up space in `#topbar`. This will happen if you float or absolute/fixed position `p`. For your second question, as pointed out by BenM, many CSS properties are not inherited from the parent/ancestor elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: If you have two questions, its better to post them seperated. It is cleaner this way.

**To question 1:** It is working actually. You can run your pasted code snippet. Likely, some other style is overwriting it. Since we cant know which one it is, the only advice i can give you is to write `!important` behind your css code like this:

```
height: 40px !important;
```

This way, nothing can overwrite it except styles that also have an !important tag.

**To question 2:**

> So elements part of a div-id don't inherit the parent-style?

Well, it depends. You can set the font-color of a div then the headlines and p tags in this div will have the same color unless you specify it otherwise like

```
#scroller{
color:blue;
}

#scroller p{
color:red;
}
```

Images dont inherit from divs. They are by default always the full image size so you have to specifiy their size seperately if it should be the full width at all times.

If it was helpful to you, pls mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: I strongly recommend figuring out what's actually wrong and **not** adding `!important`. Important was invented for end-user style sheets so people with old eyes like me can _override_ (not overwrite) site styles such as too-small text or too-low contrast.  Adding `!important` will usually lead to other styles "mysteriously" not working because there is an _important_ lurking somewhere.